# Laravel response helper file() method downloading, not displaying file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to display a file stored in storage folder using laravel's response helper. Unfortunately, every time it runs, the file is DOWNLOADED, not DISPLAYED. Below is my code:

```php
public function viewDoc($id)
{
    $a = pro_doc::findorfail($id);
    $path = storage_path('documents/'.$a->file_name);
    if ( ! File::exists($path) ) {
        abort(404);
    }
    return response()->file($path);
}
```

Im sending an id to the controller, which looks up the record and gets the file name, then attempts to open the file in a new window (this is from a link with a blank target). A new window momentarily opens, then the download begins and the window closes.
The documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#file-responses) seems to say this shouldn't happen

> The file method may be used to display a file, such as an image or PDF, directly in the user's browser instead of initiating a download.

Can anyone help me make this work? Again, Im trying to get it to open in the browser window, not download. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps Laravel can't detect what kind of file type it is due to some corruption with the file itself. Have you tried different files?

Comment: You were correct, the file was corrupt. My stupid mistake for not trying multiple files